# How to select second year,not less than first year?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Tahun Lulus</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
   <select class="form-control1" name="thn_lulus1">
      <option value="">--Pilih--</option>
      <?php                                             
         $tahunawal = 2000;                                                             
         $query = mysqli_query($k,"select YEAR(now()) as tahun");
         $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($query);                                                
         while($tahunawal<=$obj->tahun){
         ?>
      <option value="<?=$tahunawal; ?>"><?=$tahunawal; ?></option>
      <?php
         $tahunawal++;
         } 
         ?>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
   s/d
   <select class="form-control1" name="thn_lulus2">
      <option value="">--Pilih--</option>
      <?php                                             
         $tahunawal = 2000;                                                             
         $query = mysqli_query($k,"select YEAR(now()) as tahun");
         $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($query);                                                
         while($tahunawal<=$obj->tahun){
         ?>
      <option value="<?=$tahunawal; ?>"><?=$tahunawal; ?></option>
      <?php
         $tahunawal++;
         } 
         ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Above code shows combo box years only where start year is 2000 until current year.

Please help me, how to select the second year, not less than the first year?

Comment: you would have to use javascript for that. once user selects year from first select, use javascript to listen to that change and remove the years before that from second select.

Comment: may i see the example code?@Rahul

Comment: Show your sample data on option .

Comment: I removed (Solved) from the title. Accepting an answer marks it as solved. Otherwise, you can post your own answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add id in your select tag. Like -

```
<select class="form-control1" name="thn_lulus1" id="thn_lulus1">

<select class="form-control1" name="thn_lulus2" id="thn_lulus2">
```

And then -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select").on("change", function(e){
    if(e.target.id == "thn_lulus1"){
        var lulu1 = $(e.target).val();
        $.each($("#thn_lulus2 option"), function(k,v){
            if($(v).val() < lulu1) 
                $(v).attr("disabled", true);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: thx @Mahfuzur Rahman for your reply ,but cannot working in my code..hmm

Comment: sorry for late reply, is it?@Mahfuzur Rahman

'code'
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.vmap.world.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>'code'

Comment: @ Robin, before using "vmap.js", you already use a jquery lib. So no need to use another one. And in my vmap project, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Ajax.
Like this code:-

**HTML Code:**

```
<select id='dropdown1' onChange='getData(this.value);'>
    <option value="">--Pilih--</option>
    <?php                                             
        $tahunawal = 2000;                                                             
        $query = mysqli_query($k,"select YEAR(now()) as tahun");
        $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($query);                                                
        while($tahunawal<=$obj->tahun)
        {
    ?>
            <option value="<?=$tahunawal; ?>"><?=$tahunawal; ?></option>
    <?php
            $tahunawal++;
        } 
    ?>
</select>  

<select id='dropdown2'>
</select>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script>
    function getData(val)
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("dropdown2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.php?q="+val, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    //mysql connection
    $val =  $_GET['q'];
    $str = '';
    //select query contains where condition like 'Year > $val'
    $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($query);                                                
    while($tahunawal<=$obj->tahun)
    {
        $str .= '<option value="'.$tahunawal.'">'.$tahunawal.'</option>';
    }
    echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: thx @YashParekh , but i already solved this issue ..thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

One way is to disable options from the second select box that are less than the selected option from first.

Here's a fiddle-

```html
<script>
  function changeS2() {
    var selectBox1 = document.getElementById("s1");
    var selectedValue1 = parseInt(selectBox1.options[selectBox1.selectedIndex].value);
    var selectBox2 = document.getElementById("s2");
    var selectedValue2 = parseInt(selectBox2.options[selectBox2.selectedIndex].value);


    for (i = 0; i < selectBox2.options.length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(selectBox2.options[i].value) < selectedValue1) {
        selectBox2.options[i].disabled = true;
        if (parseInt(selectBox2.options[i].value) == selectedValue2) {
          // you can change it
        }
      } else {
        selectBox2.options[i].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<select name="asdf" id="s1" onchange="changeS2();">
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
</select>
<select name="qwer" id="s2">
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2004" selected>2005</option>
</select>
```